# React Native touchable opacity pressing after 2 to 5 seconds inside a FlatList

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

Good day,

I'm working on a small react native project, I'm getting data from an API, but I noticed that every time I populate the state with data from the API, the mobile app becomes slow, and when I press the Touchable Opacity inside a child element of that Flatlist it takes around 5 seconds to respond.

```
//Don't worry it's all wrapped in a parent container

<View style={globalStyles.searchContainer}>
    <TextInput style={globalStyles.textInput} placeholder="Who are you looking for? (e.g. Plumber)" onChangeText={setJob}/>
    <TouchableOpacity style={globalStyles.searchButton} onPress={handleSearch}> 
    <Text style={globalStyles.text}>Search</Text></TouchableOpacity>
</View>

<FlatList 
    data={workers}
    keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <View style={globalStyles.workerCard}>
        <Image 
            style={globalStyles.thumbnail} 
            source={{uri: globalConfig.api_url + item.profile_picture}} 
        />

        <View style={globalStyles.workerDetails}>
            <Text style={globalStyles.textDetails}>Name: {`${item.first_name} ${item.surname}`}</Text>
            <Text style={globalStyles.textDetails}>Gender: {item.gender}</Text>
            <Text style={globalStyles.textDetails}>Job: {item.job}</Text>
            <Text style={globalStyles.textDetails}>Price: {`R${item.price}`}</Text>
            <Text style={globalStyles.textDetails}>Transport fee: {`R${item.transport}`}</Text>
            <Text style={globalStyles.textDetails}>Other Job: {(item.service1) ? item.service1 : ""} </Text>
            <Text style={globalStyles.textDetails}>Other Job: {(item.service2) ? item.service2 : ""} </Text>
            <Text style={globalStyles.textDetails}>Online: {(item.available) ? "Yes" : "No"} </Text>
            <TouchableOpacity style={globalStyles.searchButton} onPress={() => bookWorker(item)}>
                 <Text style={globalStyles.text}>Book</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
         </View>
     </View>
    )}
/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, there was a function that was being called somewhere in the component, I removed it and now it's working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add an "extraData" property to your flatList. This will tell your flatList to re-render on data changes. (https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#extradata)

```
 <FlatList 
    data={workers}
    keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    extraData = {this.state.refreshing}
    renderItem={({ item }) => ...
```

Here "this.state.refreshing" could be a boolean or an incremented integer that is updated each time you call the api.

Alternatively, and most recommended, you could add a onRefresh property and move your api calls there. (https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#onrefresh). This would handle all the flatList changes for you once you update your "workers" array.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, I'm using React Hook how do you suggest I should implement this? and the API is call every I press a button that's outside the container.